# codeigniter rerouting url with some new additional parameters

Tags: php, routes, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I am using codeigniter re-route to clean up some urls.
I am aware that I can do

```
$route['product/(:num)'] = "catalog/product_lookup_by_id/$1";
```

But in some cases I have to add some extra parameters to the redirect url so that I get them as a param to the method. for example

```
$route['product_unique_and_rare'] = "catalog/product_lookup_by_id/{HERE I WANT SOME ADDITIONAL EXTRA PARAM}";
```

How to do this so that I get the value in the param of the method rather than the value in `uri->resegment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
$route['product_unique_and_rare/(:num)'] = "catalog/product_lookup_by_id/$1";
```

Get the param in product_lookup_id like this

```
function product_lookup_id($product_id){
    /*$product_id will be the passed parameter*/
}
```

So, if someone goes for `http://domain.com/product_unique_and_rare/23`, `$product_id` will get the value 23.

You can hard-code the parameter too, but I believe you aren't looking for that.

Comment: am actually looking to hard code the parameter. people will hit "http://domain.com/product_unique_and_rare" only and I want some parameters lets say x and y sent to the method.

Comment: Thanks I think hard coding also works params are passed to the method including the r-segments array